# magento multi site point to old domain in bluehost

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I created three addon domain in bluehost. I use the addon sample1.com.au to display my magento main website and it is working fine. However when I use the two other addon domain, these domain redirects to the old local domain that I have created on local. All addons are pointed to one folder. I also have created a three separate root category and created separate website, store, and store view. On my configuration I also set the base url to these addon domain.

This is my ht access:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*sample2.com.au.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=web2
SetEnvIf Host .*sample2.com.au.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host .*sample3.com.au.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=web3
SetEnvIf Host .*sample3.com.au.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

I followed this tutorial http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/. This helped me on my local set up how ever on the live server, my multisite doesn't work.

Did I missed something? or do I need additional configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!! I found the problem and the solution.

When I migrate my system to live server, the database cached was not refreshed or cleaned up. In order to clean the cache you need to create a php script called cleanup.php, save it to root directory and execute it. Thank to [How to Clear magento cache and log table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200608/how-to-clear-magento-cache-and-log-table) this solve the problem.

My .htaccess has no problem. I didn't do anything on the index.php. The tutorial http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/ is accurate.

I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add code in also index.php

in htaccess add this code

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=web2
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=web2
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=web3
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=web3
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

In index.php add code before this line `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
    case 'domain1.com':
    case 'www.domain1.com':
    $mageRunCode = 'web2';
    $mageRunType = 'website'; 
    break;
    case 'domain2.in':
    case 'www.domain2.in':
    $mageRunCode = 'web3';
    $mageRunType = 'website'; 
    break;
} 
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```